# Updating Table Column and Push the Old Data into Another Column

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, web-scraping

I'm facing some trouble with updating data and keeping the old data on the other column. I have a "price" column in the table and for the old data, I made an "old_price" column. So I am web-scraping a website and if the price changed on that website I want to update my table's price column. But the tricky part is, I need to also push the old price to "old_price" column.

So in my code, I'm checking first if have those data or not. Because I don't want to duplicate whole data. And if I haven't the data inserting those data into my database.

```
<?php
if (allestates::where('link', '=', json_encode($outlineUrl))->count() > 0) {
    $this->error('I have the DATA.');
} else {
    allestates::insertGetId($changeForMyDB);
    $this->line('DATA SAVED.');
}
```

But I also want to check if the "price" is updated in the website? If the price updated then take it and change it to old price. Also, push the old price (in my DB) into the "old_price" column. It's a little bit complicated I guess. I couldn't make it work. Any advice, help really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Here is my database structure:

```
$changeForMyDB = [
    'region' => '関西',
    'link' => json_encode($outlineUrl),
    'building_name' => '',
    'price' => '',
    'old_price' => '',
    'extend' => '',
    'address' => '',
    'total_house' => '',
    'rooms' => '',
    'cons_finish' => '',
    'entry' => '',
    'balcony' => '',
    'company_name' => '',
    'list_from' => ''
];
```

Comment: @wheelmaker updating two columns, means doesn't keep the old data? I didn't understand what you mean by saying updating two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for changes on existing rows like this:

```
if ($allestate = allestates::where('link', '=', json_encode($outlineUrl))->first()) {
    if ($allestate->price != $changeForMyDB['price']) {
        $allestate->old_price = $allestate->price;
        $allestate->fill($changeForMyDB);
        $allestate->save(); 
    }
} else {
    allestates::insertGetId($changeForMyDB);
    $this->line('DATA SAVED.');
}
```

Or you could use an observer to set the old_price column when the price changes:

In your allestate observer:

```
public function updating($allestate) 
{
    if ($allestate->wasChanged(['price']) {
        $allestate->old_price = $allestate->getOriginal('price');
        $allestate->save();
    }
}
```

Read more about setting up observers here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers

Comment: thanks for the help mate, where should I push this function, before inserting data?

Comment: This would be in it's own observer class, read through the docs link I posted there.

Comment: Also, you had mentioned (in a deleted comment) that you didn't want to "update two columns", I took that to mean you didn't want to manually update the old_price in your controller.  If this is not the case, you're probably better off skipping the observer class and just checking to see if the current price is different from the new price and handling it all in one place.

Comment: yes I guess it would be much better. just want to check price is updated or not. if updated then update database. and push the old price->"old_price" column.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of handling it all without an observer too.

Comment: yep! this is what I want. I run my web-scrape bot time to time. and if the price changes. I can scrape the new price and push the old one, right. Thank you. but also thanks for the observer too. if I need it, use :)